# What is the functionality of master in torch.distributed init_process_group?

Tags: pytorch, distributed-computing

I studied the tutorial [post](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/dist_tuto.html) about `torch.distributed` (examples are in the [gitHub repository](https://github.com/seba-1511/dist_tuto.pth/)). I see the initialzation is

```
def init_process(rank, size, fn, backend='gloo'):
    """ Initialize the distributed environment. """
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '29500'
    dist.init_process_group(backend, rank=rank, world_size=size)
    fn(rank, size)
```

I don't know the internal design of **master**. What is the functionality of master in torch.distributed init_process_group? For example, if there are 4 processes to do distributed training. Rank 0 is set as the master. And I send a tensor from Rank 1 to Rank 3. What is the communication rule defined inside the `torch.distributed`? Is it like

Rank 1 -> Rank 0 -> Rank 3, where `->` is communication or say handshake to make a connection.

Or Rank 0 (master) is used to store all ips of Rank 0-3 in a table so that any process (Rank 0-3) can immediately check the destination ip address so to make a connection like

Rank 1 -> Rank 3, where the setting is the same as the above example.

Answer (score 0):

It more close to IPs but not exactly that. To communicate between processes you need extra meta-data, like IP in your example, but more commonly known as communicators (NCCL). So, yes, master is responsible for sharing communicator addresses that each rank should join.

Master also does some additional book keeping for operational/monitoring purposes.